# Can we have a table with no primary key but a composite unique key on multiple columns in entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, primary-key, multiple-columns, unique-key

We have a following table

```
public class SomeClass
 {
   public string DocumentId { get; set;}
   public int Action { get; set;}
   public int Status { get; set;}
 }
```

We expect to have the entries as follows (A unique combination of 3 columns is accepted)

```
DocumentId   Action     Status
1             Add      Scheduled       = OK
1             Add      InProgress      = OK
2             Add      InProgress      = OK
2            Delete    Scheduled       = THIS OK 
1             Add      Scheduled       = GRRRRR! HERE ERROR
```

Obviously I cannot have DocumentID as primary key as it has duplicate entries.
I cannot have all 3 columns as Primary key since we want to update Status column based on the progress.

So is it possible/OK to create the above table **with no primary key** and **a composite unique key on those 3 columns** in EF?

Comment: Those three columns aren't unique so you can't make a unique key out of them.  And what's the point of the first and fifth record?  What does it _mean_ to have two identical records?

Comment: You can declare DocumentId,Action,Status as your key.  Whether this is a PK in the database or a unique index makes no difference to EF.  You can update a PK column directly in SQL, but probably indicates an error in your domain model.  What does one of these entities mean in your model.  Perhaps you want (DocumentId,Action) as the key and have a separate entity to track the Status History.

Comment: @PaulAbbott: Ok here is the little background, there are two processes, lets say P1 and P2. P1 adds a row into the above mentioned table and P2 will get the information from the table and performs some action. Coming to first and fifth row, whenever a new document is uploaded or a new revision of the document is uploaded we perform "Add" action. So first row might correspond to a new upload where as fifth record could correspond to a new revision being added for the same document.